# After creating a char array, it is filled with trash

Tags: c

I enter a word, and i need to create new word with same amount of symbols, and new word must be filled only with '_'.

```
int main()
{
char word[30];
cout << "Enter word: ";
gets_s(word);
cout << word;
int k = strlen(word);
cout << "Amount of letters in word: "<< k << endl;
char *temp = new char[k];
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    temp[i] = '_';
}
cout << temp << endl;

}
```

Comment: This is C++. Why aren't you using `std::string`? C strings *are* "filled with trash" by default, that's just how they are. If you're using C strings you need to use them properly and terminate that buffer or it'll keep reading until it eventually hits a zero-byte value.

Comment: You need to add one more byte for Null terminator.

Comment: `std::string` has been part of C++ since 1994 but new programmers are still trying to use char arrays. `std::string` is simpler, easier, less error prone, and more efficient (YMMV).

Comment: @john _"but new programmers are still trying to use char arrays"_ Unfortunately most of the time they're forced to do so by _absolutely incompetent_ teachers.

Comment: Avoid the lure of single-letter variables. The time they save in coding is almost always consumed by debugging, and you're going to find that you spend a LOT more time debugging than coding. Opt for descriptive identifiers.

Comment: You have allocated 30 characters for your text.  How do you prevent the User from entering more than 30 characters?

Comment: Since you are dealing with character *arrays*, use `memset` to set the array to a single value.  Don't forget to set the last slot to '\0'.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With C strings, which are really obnoxious to use and can usually be avoided in C++, you **must** NUL terminate your character buffers:

```
char *temp = new char[k + 1];
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
  temp[i] = '_';
}
temp[k] = 0; // Terminated
```

Without that you'll read on into random memory and see all sorts of garbage.

This would be a lot easier with `std::string`:

```
std::string temp;
for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
  temp += '_';
}
```

You don't have to remember to NUL terminate because `std::string` doesn't need it, the Standard Library uses a different method internally and it's handled for you automatically.

**But wait, there's more!**

If you act now and use `std::string` you have access to amazing tools like this:

```
std::string temp(k, '_');
```

Even easier!

Comment: Extending to reading with strings: `std::string s; std::cin >> s;` and we wouldn't have to care for buffer overflow either...

Comment: @Aconcagua Exactly, `std::string` is the difference between using an airplane and walking in bare feet on the ice.

Answer (score -1):

in c++ , when you create array or struct in runtime (dont matter in heap or in stack)  all values filled with trash.

to prevent possible error :

for structs :

```
typedef struct
{
    int age;  
    char name[30];

}person;

person emptyPerson;  // emptyPerson age is 0 , name is {0,0,0...}

void runtimeCreatePerson()
{
    person runtTimePerson;
    cout << runtTimePerson.name<< endl;  // this will print garbage values 

    person runtTimePerson2 = emptyPerson; // now runtimePerson has same values with emptyResponse(copy of)

    cout << runtTimePerson2.name<< endl;  // this will print ""

}

int main()
{
    runtimeCreatePerson();
}
```

for Array  you have to fill it after create:

```
int i = 0;
int main()
{
    char runtimeArray[50];
    cout << runtimeArray<< endl;  // this will print garbage values 
    for(i=0 ; i < 50 ; i++)
        runtimeArray[i] = 0;
    cout << runtimeArray<< endl;  // this will print ""
}
```